# How to run scripts after deviceready event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, unit-testing, jasmine

I've faced with a problem when running jasmine tests for Cordova application: I have an html page (Jasmine 2.4 SpecRunner.html) with scripts in a `<head>` to be loaded (plugins, services, controllers, etc) and the last included file in a `<head>` is a test file. In a body I have a `deviceready` event listener. But when I run tests against android emulator, my tests is always executed before `deviceready`, and it doesn't see plugins(i.e. error "device is not defined").

So the question is: how to delay execution of test files  exactly after `deviceready` event?

My SpecRunner.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <title>SportsWellness</title>


        <script src="scripts/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.css">

    <!-- Jasmine Modules -->

    <script src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.4.1/boot.js"></script>

    <!-- SportsWellness references -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />

    <!-- AngularJS modules -->
    <script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-mocks.js"></script>

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Application scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Controllers-->
    <!-- Script tags  -->

    <!-- Include Services -->
    <!-- Script tags  -->

    <!-- Include Directives -->
    <!-- Script tags  -->

    <!-- Include Configuration Scripts -->
    <!-- Script tags  -->

    <!-- Include specs to run -->
    <script src="tests/ServicesTests/ReminderService.spec.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>    
    <script type="application/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }, false);
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is not as beautiful as I want it to be, but I changed jasmine/boot.js file and replaced `window.onload` function with `document.addEventListener('deviceready', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run the onDeviceReady and then your scripts inside a function on the handler?

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    onDeviceReady();
    if ("splashscreen" in navigator) navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    // other script things
}, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // stuff
}
```

Pretty sure it's synchronous (I think that's the right word - it will wait until the `inDeviceReady` function finishes before continuing). Correct me if this is incorrect :P